# delayed_job how to set .delay(run_at: from (attribute).time.from_now)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am using delayed_job successfully like:

```
 Mailer.delay(run_at: 1.minutes.from_now).my_mail(my model)
```

I would like to set the minutes with an attribute, in this case called :frequency . 
i have tried with :frequency/frequency:/(frequency)/[frequency][:frequency]

one of the errors I'm getting is

```
undefined method `minutes' for :frequency:Symbol
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? or should i do something else? 
How should i do it? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It actually worked as "#{:frequency}" if you re-post your answer i will validate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
frequency = 10
"#{frequency}".to_i.minute.from_now
```

Comment: I actually anticipated myself, as i saw no errors, but it is sending the email immediately, no matter what value gets passed into "frequency". I am passing a value through a form. Any idea on how i could correct this? thanks for your help!

Comment: Try writing the `"#{frequency}".to_i.minute.from_now` part to a variable and verify that it is getting the correct value as expected by using `puts` or `logger.info`. Am guessing frequency is being set to zero.

Comment: Ok, finally got it right. it is "#{mymodel.frequency}" . Thank you for your help.