# how to run rails commands in system command in rails when we run through delayed jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

```
def process_order
  OrderProcess.delay(run_at:1.minutes.from_now).processing_order(params[:id])
    redirect_to '/'
end
```

> when process_order is executed 
>   it will execute delayed job

```
class OrderProcess
  def self.processing_order(order_id)
    system("rails generate controller welcome index")
  end
end
```

> when we remove delay(run_at:1.minutes.from_now) and process_order then rails commands in system command are getting executed but when we run through delayed job rails commands are not getting executed
>
> thanks in advance

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27582269/delayed-job-how-to-set-delayrun-at-from-attribute-time-from-now

Comment: Thanks for the response @MonsieurSlim, i am trying to run rails commands in delayed job and i am able to run rake commands.

Comment: This should help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358805/rails-execute-script-as-background-job